# Спарсить из xml документа

Tags: c#, xml, парсер, xmlparser

Есть xml, полученный из Excel. Разметка выглядит примерно так, только строк значительно больше и  блок `Data` c `"Number"` только один:

XML:

```
<Row>
  <Cell>
    <Data ss:Type="String">AAPL US Equity</Data>
  </Cell>
  <Cell>
    <Data ss:Type="Number">150.25</Data>
  </Cell>
  <Cell>
    <Data ss:Type="Number">1</Data>
  </Cell>
</Row>
<Row>
  <Cell>
    <Data ss:Type="String">GOOGL Equity</Data>
  </Cell>
  <Cell>
    <Data ss:Type="Number">942.17</Data>
  </Cell>
  <Cell>
    <Data ss:Type="Number">2</Data>
  </Cell>
</Row>
<Row>...</Row>
<Row>...</Row>
```

Использую `XmlTextReader`, чтобы выбрать все значения из блока `<Data ss:Type="String">`ВОТ ЭТО`</Data >` (AAPL US Equity 
 и GOOGL Equity):

```
public void Go()
{
    XmlTextReader ValueReader = new XmlTextReader("///book1.xml");
    try
    {
        while (ValueReader.Read())
        {
            switch (ValueReader.NodeType)
            {
                case XmlNodeType.Element:
                    if (ValueReader.Name == "Cell")
                    {
                        ValueReader.MoveToElement();
                        var X = ValueReader.ReadOuterXml();
                        XmlDocument usdXmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
                        usdXmlDocument.LoadXml(X);
                        XmlNode xmlNode = usdXmlDocument.SelectSingleNode(@"Data ss:Type=""String""/Data");
                        MessageBox.Show(xmlNode.InnerText.ToString(), "");

                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ex.Source);
    }
}
```

Исключение

> Data ss:Type="String"/Number имеет недопустимый указатель(токен).

Буду благодарен за любую подсказку.

Comment: А как usdXmlDocument  хоть как-то относится к первоначальному xml, что вы в него запросы select делаете?

Comment: @vitidev спасибо, поправил. но пока ошибка та же

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov добавил текст

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В метод `SelectSingleNode` нужно передавать xpath-выражение. Вот это - `@"Data ss:Type=""String""/Data"` - что-то странное, но никак не xpath.

Если использовать именно ваш алгоритм извлечения данных, с применением `XmlDocument`, то минимальные изменения, которые нужно внести в код, это взять правильный xpath и добавить менеджер пространств имён. Пространства имён обязательно нужно учитывать, без этого никак.

```
var manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(usdXmlDocument.NameTable);
manager.AddNamespace("ss", "some-namespace");
XmlNode xmlNode = usdXmlDocument.SelectSingleNode(@"/Cell/Data[@ss:Type='String']", manager);
if (xmlNode != null)
    MessageBox.Show(xmlNode.InnerText.ToString(), "");
```

Вместо `some-namespace` укажите именно то, что у вас в XML. Где его взять? Ищите в своём xml объявление наподобие `xmlns:ss="some-namespace"`. Вероятнее всего, оно будет в самом начале, в корневом элементе документа.

---

Код можно существенно упростить и ускорить его работу.

Класс `XmlTextReader` считается устаревшим. Вместо него следует создавать экземпляры `XmlReader` с помощью статического метода `Create`.

После использования все `Disposable` объекты следует освобождать. Проще всего это делать с применением конструкции `using`.

Класс `XmlReader` имеет много полезных методов. В нашем случае - однородная структура xml - удобно применить `ReadToFollowing`. А для чтения атрибута - `GetAttribute`. Пространство имён при этом обязательно нужно указывать! Естественно, заменить `some-namespace` на настоящий.

Найдя элемент с нужным атрибутом, читаем его значение `ReadElementContentAsString`.

```
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create("test.xml"))
{
    while (reader.ReadToFollowing("Data"))
    {
        if (reader.GetAttribute("Type", "some-namespace") == "String")
            MessageBox.Show(reader.ReadElementContentAsString());
    }
}
```

Это весь код!

Comment: поясните пожалуйста, что такое пространства имен и Xpath?

Comment: @Сергей - [XPath](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) - язык, с помощью которого производится поиск в xml-документах. [Пространство имён](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%91%D0%BD_(XML)) - это как фамилия у человека. В двух словах это не объяснить, желательно прочесть толстую книгу.